# Why does javascript works only if logged in?

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to implement a simple script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#masthead').outerHeight()) {
        $("#masthead").addClass("minimize");
    } else{
        $("#masthead").removeClass("minimize");
    }
});
});
```

It works perfectly when the user is logged in in to WP. For regular users the script gets loaded in the footer but does nothing.

I also get this error from the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not definedfixed-menu.js?ver=20150318:1 (anonymous function)
```

PD: I used `wp_enqueue_script` in my `functions.php` as I do with any other external js:

```
function nevermind_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'nevermind-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'nevermind-google-fonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,900,300italic,400italic|Droid+Serif');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'nevermind-font-awesome', 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'nevermind-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20120206', true );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'nevermind-fixed-menu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fixed-menu.js', array(), '20150318', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nevermind_scripts' );
```

Comment: How do you call the script in your functions.php? What's the exact line?

Comment: Just updated the question with my functions.php

Comment: Just a future request, please work on your formatting before posting your question/answer. Tip: For code, if you add code in the editor, highlight it and click on once on the `{}` sign above the editor. This will ad your code in a code block. For function names or one liner code, use backticks, the `~` button on my keyboard. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the tips!The Editor is not very friendly. I wonder if we can submit an update for that?

Comment: Just to comment on your issue, there is nothing different between loading scripts for logged in or logged out users. They load in the same fashion regardless by default. Your code is correct. Either a plugin or a theme function is causing this issue to happen. Test your code on a bundled theme, clear **all** caches and deactivate all your plugins one by one and test after each one. You should be able to find the culprit in this fashion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'nevermind-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array('jquery') );
```

It is possible that jQuery is not enqueued, and you are not declaring it as a dependency for your script. Being logged in, automatically enqueues jQuery.

**EDIT:** Console log says `jQuery is not defined`. Did you add a `jQuery(document).ready($)` function for the fixed-menu.js functions?

Comment: *Being logged in, automatically enqueues jQuery*. Bull unfortunately, jquery is loaded regardless being logged in or not by default.

Comment: No, it's not. Unless you have another script which requires jQuery as a dependency. Can you see any console errors?

Comment: Just updated the questión with the error from the console.

Comment: It says "jQuery is not defined". Did you add a jQuery(document).ready($) function for the fixed-menu.js functions?

Comment: So simple, I thought JQuery was already enqueued. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### CDNs, remote resources and cross origin requests

You might want to replace the `http:` for your CDNs first. It could be that there are cross origin request problems when using that. Omitting the protocol allows the browser to chose the right protocol depending on the situation. The fixed protocol often is a problem in Chrome - the "overprotective parent".

### Dependency Injection<sup>light</sup> in JavaScript

Aside from that, you can always test if some dependency is loaded. This can be done easily by checking it into a self invoking function and logging it to the console:

```
( function( $ ) {
    "use strict";
    console.log( $ );
} )( jQuery || {} );
```

This means that you will either get the full `jQuery` object logged, or - if it failed to load early enough - the `{}`/empty object. If the latter is the case, then you can go with what @Ciprian suggested: Add your dependency when registering/enqueuing your script:

```
wp_enqueue/register_script(
    $handle,
    plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'assets/js/script.js',
    array( 'jquery' ),
    filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'assets/js/script.js' ),
    true
);
```

You might want to use one of the following functions for your URL/Path - dump in case you are unsure of what you get

- `get_template_directory()` - Path to the parent theme root dir
- `get_stylesheet_directory()` - Path to the child theme root dir
- `get_template_directory_uri()` - URL to the parent theme root dir
- `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` - URL to the child theme root dir
- `plugin_dir_path( __FILE___ )` - Root of the current file, no matter if in child/parent theme or a plugin. Trailing slashed result.
- `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )` - Root of the current file - in a plugin. Trailing slashed result.

**PROTip:** This uses the "file last modified time"/`filemtime()`, a UNIX timestamp as version number/query argument to break through browser cache on demand.

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't declaring JQuery as a dependency. Thanks for the filemtime() tip.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by Pieter Goosen to check the plugins worked for me.  Was caused by Fast Velocity Minify plugin.  Clearing the cache didn't work either, the only way to get around it was to disable the plugin and re-enable it after development was complete.